# Spring 3 - Dynamic Autowiring at runtime based on another object attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring 3.1 MVC application and for one of my scenarios, I had to write two implementations of a DAO. I would like to know how to autowire this in a service layer
 based on another object's attribute.

For example,

```
    class Vehicle {
        private name;
        private type;
        ..
        ..
        ..
    } 

    @Service
    class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService {

            // There are two implementations to this DAO
            // if Vehicle.type == "CAR", inject CarDAO
            // if Vehicle.type == "TRAIN", inject TrainDAO 
            @Autowired
            private VehicleDAO vehicleDAO ;

    }

    @Repository
    class CarDAO implements VehicleDAO {

    }

    @Repository
    class TrainDAO implements VehicleDAO {

    }
```

If my Vehicle is a Car, I need to autowire CarDAO and if it's a train, I need to autowire TrainDAO

What is the best way to implement this in spring 3.1.

I was hoping to use either context property place holders or  @Qualifier annotation but both these are kind of restricted to lookup based on some property. 
I am not sure how to do this at runtime based on the property of another object.

Comment: I think you need to implement a factory provider, which will give you the correct instance of DAO based on the type of the vehicle

Comment: Is vehicle a argument to a method in the service

Comment: Vehicle is available in @Model. I am assuming it can be used to construct the Service

Comment: no, if it is a Model, then it is a runtime value and it has to be passed as a method argument, so you won't be able to use it for autowiring the values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My solution would be as follows:

a method isResponsibleFor in the VehicleDao interface:

```
interface VehicleDao {
    public boolean isResponsibleFor(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

example implementation:

```
@Repository
class CarDAO implements VehicleDAO {
    public boolean isResponsibleFor(Vehicle vehicle) {
        return "CAR".equals(vehicle.getType());
    }
}
```

then autowire a [list of all VehicleDao-implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) in the VehicleService:

```
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService {

    @Autowired
    private List<VehicleDao> vehicleDaos;

    private VehicleDao daoForVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
         foreach(VehicleDao vehicleDao : vehicleDaos) {
              if(vehicleDao.isResponsibleFor(vehicle) {
                   return vehicleDao;
              }
         }

         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported vehicleType");
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Vehicle vehicle) {
         daoForVehicle(vehicle).save(vehicle);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to modify the service when you are adding a new vehicleType at a later time - you just need to add a new VehicleDao-implementation.

Comment: Clean solution from my point of view. This is the approach we took also. Just in the 'isResponsible' method do not use string but class comparison. You can even have a fallback implementation if you use one autowired field with a concrete implementation instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Felix. I was not aware we could wire a list of beans of a particular type

Answer (score 18):

There is an cleaner option to accomplish this strategy. We know Spring is smart enough to inject where it sees a bean that it has control over, so when it sees your `VehicleDAO` with an `@Autowire` or `@Resource` annotation, it will correctly inject that concrete implementation.

Keeping that in mind, this will work anywhere you ask Spring to perform dependency injection, using a `Map<>` or a `List<>` for instance.

```java
// Injects the map will all VehicleDAO implementations where key = the
// concrete implementation (The default name is the class name, otherwise you 
// can specify the name explicitly).
@Autowired
private Map<String, VehicleDAO> vehicleDAO;

// When you want to use a specific implementaion of VehicleDAO, just call the  
// 'get()' method on the map as in:
...
vehicleDAO.get("carDAO").yourMethod();
...
```

Comment: Nice.  I never knew that despite years of Autowiring.  Also see: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Comment: Fantastic suggestion. How would we test the Map injection though, using a Junit Test class

Comment: This is perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Since Vehicle is a `@Model` it is a runtime value, you won't be able to use it for autowiring values.

The vehicle has to be passed to the service methods as an argument.

public interface VehicleService {
    void doSomething(Vehicle vehicle);
}

Assuming both `CarDao` and `TrainDAO` are implementing the same `VehicleDao` Service, other wise it won't make much sense.

So in your `VehicleServiceImpl` I would recommend you to write a method like `getVehicleDao(Vehicle v){}` to get the correct instance of the dao.

```
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService {

    @Resource(name="carDAO")
    private VehicleDao carDAO ;


    @Resource(name="trainDAO")
    private VehicleDao trainDAO ;

    private VehicleDao getDao(Vehicle v){
        if(v instanceof Train){
            return trainDao;
        } else if(v instanceof Car) {
            return carDao;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("unsupported vehicle type");
        }
    }

    void doSomething(Vehicle vehicle){
        VehicleDao dao = getDao(vehicle);
        dao.doSomethind(vehicle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both carDao and vehicleDao implement the same interface. Is it a good practice to autowire an implementation, rather than an interface.

Comment: @aprajitha no, i thought they are also interfaces.

Comment: this would require checking for all different implementations of Vehicle, therefore will be very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Please one note: previous solution is great and simple, but spring is creating each instance of each bean.

So my solution is to create abstract class VehicleService instead of interface

then in appContext

```
@Bean
@Primary
VehicleService paymentProviderService()
{
    return ...new (your requested instance by your own)...
}
```