# Spring Autowire Bean with multiple Interface Implementations, define Implementation in method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I am new to spring and spring boot, so hopefully it is not a silly question.

I have an interface with several implementations. Implementations are annotated with `@Component("NameOfImpl")`.

My goal is to autowire a bean with selected implementation. In a normal case I can do it with `@Autowired @Qualifier("NameOfImpl")`, but my Problem is I want to select an Implementation in a method like:

```
public void doSomethingMethod(){ 
      for(String line: configFile){
                String[] values = line.split(";");

                if (values[0].equals("A")) {
                    //here I want to select an bean implementation

                }
                else if (values[0].equals("B")) {
                    //here I want to select another bean implementation

                }
      }
      bean.doSomething();
    }
```

How can I achieve that? What do you suggest? 
Thank you!

Comment: you can remove the autowiring since you are instantiating the implementations manually

Comment: My goal is not to instantiate them manually

Comment: using `new` means instantiating ..

Comment: Yes, I know, I need something instead of using new Impl(); I edit the post

Comment: take a look at this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284851/spring-3-dynamic-autowiring-at-runtime-based-on-another-object-attribute

Answer (score 11):

You can ask Spring to inject a `Map` of beans. The keys in the map will be the beans' names.

If you have an interface named `Example`

```
public interface Example {

}
```

And two implementations:

```
@Component("foo")
public class FooExample implements Example {

}

@Component("bar")
public class BarExample implements Example {

}
```

You can have a map of `Example` beans injected:

```
@Component
public class ExampleConsumer {

    private final Map<String, Example> examples;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleConsumer(Map<String, Example> examples) {
        this.examples = examples;
    }
}
```

In this case the map will contain two entries:

- `"foo"` -> `FooExample` instance
- `"bar"` -> `BarExample` instance

Answer (score 0):

This is also working

```
public interface Example {

}

@Component("foo")
public class FooExample implements Example {

}

@Component("bar")
public class BarExample implements Example {

}
```

You can simply Auto wire them

```
@Component
public class ExampleConsumer {

 @Autowired
    private final Map<String, Example> examples;


}
```

"foo" -> FooExample instance
"bar" -> BarExample instance