# Creating different Oauth2RestTemplates based on credentials on Runtime

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a OAuth2RestTemplate defined as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class TestOauth{
        
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(){
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate= new OAuth2RestTemplate(buildResourceDetails());
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()));
return restTemplate;
}
    
@Bean
public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails buildResourceDetails(){
ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setClientId("TestId");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("TestSecret");
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("TestURI");
return resourceDetails;
}
```

Now, in the calling class, I have it annotated as below and it works fine.

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

I want to make this functionality generic and create the templates based of off clientId, secret and URI. How can I achieve this? Is creating multiple @bean methods (Separate method for each credentials) and based on the caller credentials, picking the corresponding bean from a map maybe the only way to achieve this?

I tried keeping only one @bean method and passing params to restTemplate method but I keep running into *No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found* error

Please advise

Comment: How many clientId do you have?

Comment: About 3 right now, but we are thinking of it to grow to 20 in near future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few number of `clientId` such as 3 or 4 it's ok to have multiple bean of type  `OAuth2RestTemplate`  with different name and use them. if you want to go for this approach read the following link to autowire multiple bean in a map:

[Spring Autowire Bean with multiple Interface Implementations, define Implementation in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996326/spring-autowire-bean-with-multiple-interface-implementations-define-implementat)

But if you know the number of `ClientId` will dynamically change based on some parameters you can use one bean of type `OAuth2RestTemplate` and change the value of `clientId` header at runtime using `RestTemplate Interceptor`.

Read the following link to know how to use `Interceptor`:

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/clienthttprequestinterceptor/

If you are determined to pass client Id at runtime based on parameter in request  you can do that this way:

```
private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders(String clientId, String secret)
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("client_id", clientId);
    headers.add("client_secret", secret);
    return headers;
}

private void yourserviceMethod() 
{
    String theUrl = "http://blah.blah.com:8080/rest/api/blah";
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders("clintId", "secret", "accessToken");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("Result - status ("+ response.getStatusCode() + ") has body: " + response.hasBody());
    }
    catch (Exception eek) {
        System.out.println("** Exception: "+ eek.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Super.. similar to soap handlers right? Let me check it out thanks.

Comment: Actually the interceptor won't work since the credentials are selected based on certain conditions and not are not stored in a property file.

Comment: You mean you want to decide which `clientId` to be set as header in your service? If it is your requirement you can set `clientId` as header when calling Restemplate methods in your service

Comment: How can I pass the clientid to interceptor at runtime?

Comment: I cannot distinguish which clientid to choose from based on the details from the request in interceptor.

Comment: Can I just not have EnableOAuth2Client, Configuration and Bean annotations and just use a regular factory pattern to return the OauthRestTemplate. Would that work?

Comment: I don't know what type of token your are using but I've just edited my answer to show you how set `clientId` at runtime., if it doesn't work for you don't hesitate to ask your question